# Java Regular Expression doesn't find a match

Tags: java, regex

I am having Java regex issues. The string I need matching follows this pattern: `378-Columbian Forecast Yr-NB-Q-Columbian_NB` I need to extract what is between the first and second `-`.

```
Pattern modelRegEx = Pattern.compile("[^-]{15,}[^-]");
Matcher m = modelRegEx.matcher(temp);
String model = m.group(0);
```

Here is my reasoning behind this regex `[^-]{15,}[^-]`:

I only want what is between the hyphens so I used `[^-]`. There are multiple instances of text between hyphens so I picked a number that was large enough it won't pick up on the smaller matches. So I used `{15,}`

My error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
 at alfaSpecificEditCheck.tabTest.main(tabTest.java:21)
```

When I tested my regex pattern against the string here: http://regexpal.com/ the pattern matched.  When I tested using this tester more specifically for Java (http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) The results were the match wasn't found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make regex engine *find* its match first. Generally to let us iterate over all matching parts we use

```
Pattern modelRegEx = Pattern.compile("[^-]{15,}[^-]");
Matcher m = modelRegEx.matcher(temp);
while(m.find()){// <-- add this
    String model = m.group(0);
    //do stuff with each match you will find
}
```

BTW if you want to find at least 15 of something and once more then you want to find it at least 16 times, so it seems that your regex can be rewritten as

```
Pattern modelRegEx = Pattern.compile("[^-]{16,}");
//                                         ^^
```